# how to dynamically add the states and cities names of india in jsp select control without using db

Tags: java, jsp

I want to dynamically add all states and cities name of india in my java web application using select control.

Is there any plugin to add that?

please anyone help to do this...

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should at least define the term "dynamically".

Comment: i want to add all states and cities name of india not directly such as <option value='Andhra Pradesh'>Andhra Pradesh</option> or using db... @qqilihq

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Country {
    public java.util.List<String> getItems() {
        java.util.List<String> stateList = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("State1");
        list.add("State2");
        list.add("State3");
        ------
        ------ // add rest of the states
        return stateList;
    }
}
```

Now use this list in your JSP like below

```
<body>
    <jsp:useBean id="stateList" class="Country" scope="page"/>
    State:
    <select id="drp_States">
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${stateList.items}">
            <option value="${item}">${item}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</body>
```

// Second way is directly add the list of all states to select tag in jsp.

```
<select>
<option value='Andaman and Nicobar Islands'>Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
<option value='Andhra Pradesh'>Andhra Pradesh</option>
<option value='Arunachal Pradesh'>Arunachal Pradesh</option>
<option value='Assam'>Assam</option>
<option value='Bihar'>Bihar</option>
<option value='Chandigarh'>Chandigarh</option>
<option value='Chhattisgarh'>Chhattisgarh</option>
<option value='Dadra and Nagar Haveli'>Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option>
<option value='Daman and Diu'>Daman and Diu</option>
<option value='Delhi'>Delhi</option>
<option value='Goa'>Goa</option>
<option value='Gujarat'>Gujarat</option>
<option value='Haryana'>Haryana</option>
<option value='Himachal Pradesh'>Himachal Pradesh</option>
<option value='Jammu and Kashmir'>Jammu and Kashmir</option>
<option value='Jharkhand'>Jharkhand</option>
<option value='Karnataka'>Karnataka</option>
<option value='Kerala'>Kerala</option>
<option value='Lakshadweep'>Lakshadweep</option>
<option value='Madhya Pradesh'>Madhya Pradesh</option>
<option value='Maharashtra'>Maharashtra</option>
<option value='Manipur'>Manipur</option>
<option value='Meghalaya'>Meghalaya</option>
<option value='Mizoram'>Mizoram</option>
<option value='Nagaland'>Nagaland</option>
<option value='Odisha'>Odisha</option>
<option value='Puducherry'>Puducherry</option>
<option value='Punjab'>Punjab</option>
<option value='Rajasthan'>Rajasthan</option>
<option value='Sikkim'>Sikkim</option>
<option value='Tamil Nadu'>Tamil Nadu</option>
<option value='Telengana'>Telengana</option>
<option value='Tripura'>Tripura</option>
<option value='Uttar Pradesh'>Uttar Pradesh</option>
<option value='Uttarakhand'>Uttarakhand</option>
<option value='West Bengal'>West Bengal</option>
</select>
```

Its same for Cities even ..!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in your answer you just added the states name directly. Is there any other way to add all states and cities name in another way...